# Probability that the direction of particle is same

Tags: combinatorics

Six particles in a container can move in only one of six directions: up, down, left, right, forward, and backward. If they move randomly such that each collides and changes direction every $1.00×10^{-6} s$ for how many seconds during a $24.0$ hour day are all six particles moving in the same direction?

I am not able to find the probability that all the particles are in same direction. I tried using $1/6^6$ but it didn't work out neither did $1/5^6$. What should be the probability then?

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that the probability that each is in some direction is independent from the other particles, the probability that all particles are moving in the same direction at any given time is $6^{-5}$.

Comment: But each time a particle collide its direction has to change so if one particle had speed in U direction its new speed can only be from DLRFB so shouldn't it be 5/5^6?

Comment: Never mind got it

Comment: @mathnoob123 You fix the direction of one of the particles, then you look at the probability that all other particles go in that direction.

Answer (score 0):

At each seconds, the probability, $p$ that every particle moves in the same direction is $6\times \frac1{6^5}=\frac1{6^5}=\frac1{7776}$ because every direction can be the common one and the directions exclude each other. We run $N=24\times 3600=86400$ experiments. So, this is a binomial distribution with parameters $N, p$ and we are interested in the expectation of running all the particles in the same direction. This is then

$$Np=\frac{86400}{7776}\approx 11.$$

This is not seconds yet; this is the number of events. But every such event lasts one second. So, the answer is $$11\text{ sec.} $$

(-- On average.)